# Even distribution of the replacement of words in a paragraph

Tags: javascript

Apologies if this is a dumb question - and seeing that the problem is mathematical in nature rather than a coding issue, I'm not sure how appropriate it is here, but I thought I'd ask.

My problem is as follows:

At the top of the page is a slider, which outputs a value from 0 to 100, depending on the slider's position.

Beneath this I have a paragraph of text that contains x number of pronouns (each wrapped in a `<span class='pronoun'>` tag), which I would like to replace with the person's name. In other words, I'm trying to replace every nth pronoun, the value of n being dependent on the position for the slider.

For example: (if my paragraph has 16 pronouns)

- (Slider = 0) - no pronouns are replaced.
- (slider = 25) - 4 pronouns are replaced, more or less equally distributed.
- (slider = 50) - 8 pronouns are replaced, more or less equally distributed.
- (slider = 75) - 12 pronouns are replaced, more or less equally distributed.
- (slider = 100) - 16 pronouns are replaced.

Odd number of pronouns, or other positions of the slider on the scale might prove to be a little trickier, but rounding to the nearest integer should be accurate enough for what I am trying to achieve.

My current attempts are bringing me to this:

```
    $('#pronouns').on('input', function() {
    var slider = $(this).val();
    $('#commentContainer').find('.sortable').each(function(index) {
        var innerDivId = $(this).attr('id');
        var name = atob($(this).data('all').name);
        var comment = $(this).find('p');
        var count = comment.children('.pronoun').length;
        var i = 0;
        var child = 0;
        var children = [];
        while (i <= count) {
            n = parseInt(count/((count/100)*slider));
            child = (n * i) + 1;
            children.push(child);
            comment.children('.pronoun:nth-child(' + child + ')').html(name);
            i++;
        }
        console.log("slider is " + slider + ", pronouns : " + count + ", i is: " + i + ", n is: " + n + ", children are: " + children.toString());
    });
});
```

However, as it stands my slider is having the opposite effect - the distribution is becoming larger, not smaller, as the slider goes to the right.

Any suggestions or pointers would be appreciated. There may also be an alternate solution I haven't remotely thought of, and I'm equally open to suggestions in that regard.

Comment: I'm suspicious of using that `.pronoun:nth-child` selector... It seems easier to just index into the `comment.children('.pronoun')` list

Comment: You should post your HTML and make this into a snippet. There is a lot going on here that's otherwise unclear.